# Page Metadata Component Link

Tags: 2013, java, dd4t-2

I have a Component Link in the Metadata Section of a Page.

I cannot see the content of this Component in the Page JSON which is published to the Broker DB.

Is it possible to get the content of the Component? Or is it necessary/possible to query the Content Delivery API to fetch the content of this Component?

Link Level is set to 5. Have try to set to 20 an no success.

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify what the `LinkLevels` is set at, in the Page Template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the link level is set on the wrong TBB.

Since all DD4T TBBs use the same parameter schema, the TBBs seem to use the value from the first TBB in which the value was set.

So if you don't the link levels in the very first TBB, it will use the default, even if you set it further down.

In your scenario, the link level was not set on "Add inherited metadata to page" so it was using the default, even though "Generate dynamic page" had the link level set to 20.

[image]

Comment: Mind you setting a link level to 20 sounds really bad to me (5 is already high if you ask me), that would include so many linked items that you are risking publishing all Components in your CMS with every Page.

Comment: Agreed - 20 was set as a test when it wasn't working.